# replace doesn't replace all whitespace

Tags: sqlite, replace

The field `var2` in my table has this value: "  89 5426  "

When running this query:

```
SELECT replace(var2,' ','A') as var2 WHERE .....
```

the result is "AA89 5426AA".

Why is the middle whitespace not replaced?

Comment: Possibly the whitespace in the middle is not  a space but some other whitespace.

Comment: thank,what sort of other whitespace ?

Comment: thank there is a way in sqllite to replace more than one entity

Comment: it's very strange , if i take the result after the request and i try to clean with a regexp in JS all space are replaced. So i think that it's a whitespace , and i dont understand why the request does not do the good work

Answer (score 0):

Im having the same issue with sqlite3, Python 3.5

```
select replace(replace(replace(price,'-',''),',',''),' ','') 
from property
```

returns `8 250 000` for the string `8 250 000,-`, so the whitespace is not removed.

**UPDATE: The solution was to do the following:**

```
replace(replace(replace(replace(price,'-',''),',',''),' ',''),char(160),'')
```

turned out that the blank space returned `unicode() => 160`